# Get details of RMI call in Weblogic jms MessagingBridge

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic-10.x

I see stuck thread in Weblogic console, and there are no project-specific classes in it's threaddump. I realize that something is working, cause it may read from socket, wait for object lock etc., so it is not actually stuck, it is long running. And there are no long running queries in DB.

How can I get know, what code is running in this thread?
Thread dump is below

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)
java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:496)
weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.connect(MuxableSocketT3.java:401)
weblogic.rjvm.t3.ConnectionFactoryT3.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryT3.java:34)
weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1777)
weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.findOrCreateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1417)
weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:437)
weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:396)
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.ensureConnectionEstablished(RJVMImpl.java:304)
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.getOutputStream(RJVMImpl.java:348)
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.getRequestStreamInternal(RJVMImpl.java:610)
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.getRequestStream(RJVMImpl.java:561)
weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.getOutboundRequest(RJVMImpl.java:787)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.getOutboundRequest(BasicRemoteRef.java:159)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:211)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ReaderBlockGetterImpl_1033_WLStub.getBlock(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ReaderHandler.refreshCacheIfNeeded(ReaderHandler.java:175)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ReaderHandler.read(ReaderHandler.java:56)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setReaderContentsForStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9774)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setCharacterStreamInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9629)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setCharacterStreamInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9570)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9561)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setCharacterStream(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:656)
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(PreparedStatement.java:511)
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl.setCharacterStream(PreparedStatementImpl.java:199)
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl.setCharacterStream(PreparedStatementImpl.java:135)
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper_WLSkel.internalInvoke1(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OraclePreparedStatementWrapper_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:589)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:477)
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:473)
weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing stuck threads, you have a couple of options to detect where it is coming from:

- In the weblogic console, go to `Servers -> <server name> -> Monitoring -> Threads tab`

  - From there you an sort all of the threads and potentially see your stuck thread
  - You can also click `Dump Thread Stacks` and see if something is stuck
- Use jConsole , which comes with the JDK (or something similar) to connect to your weblogic server

  - Click the threads tab and then click `Detect Deadlock` button to see if a deadlock has occurred, in other words, a permanently stuck thread

More ideas since it does seem DB related:

- In the weblogic console, go to `Data Sources -> <jdbc source name> -> Connection Pool tab`

  - In the advanced section, set `Statement Timeout` and have a look at other settings like `Test Connections on Reserve`
- In the weblogic console, go to `Servers -> <server name> -> Tuning and Overload`

  - Increase the `Max Stuck Thread Time` if you do not want these events reported every 600 seconds, the default value